# FindShortestPath does not work

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The FindShortestPath doesn't work in this graph, can someone tel me what's wrong?

```
    v={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239}
e={1<->2,1<->12,1<->13,2<->3,2<->10,2<->12,3<->4,3<->8,3<->10,4<->5,4<->7,4<->8,5<->6,5<->7,5<->9,6<->9,6<->11,7<->8,7<->9,7<->14,7<->15,8<->10,8<->14,8<->16,9<->11,9<->15,9<->18,10<->12,10<->16,10<->17,11<->18,12<->13,12<->17,13<->19,14<->15,14<->16,14<->20,14<->23,15<->18,15<->21,15<->23,16<->17,16<->20,16<->25,17<->19,17<->22,17<->25,18<->21,18<->24,19<->22,19<->26,20<->23,20<->25,20<->28,21<->23,21<->24,21<->27,22<->25,22<->26,22<->29,23<->27,23<->28,23<->31,24<->27,24<->30,25<->28,25<->29,25<->32,26<->29,26<->33,27<->30,27<->31,27<->34,28<->31,28<->32,28<->35,29<->32,29<->33,29<->36,30<->34,30<->37,31<->34,31<->35,31<->38,32<->35,32<->36,32<->39,33<->36,33<->40,34<->37,34<->38,34<->41,35<->38,35<->39,35<->42,36<->39,36<->40,36<->43,37<->41,37<->44,38<->41,38<->42,38<->45,39<->42,39<->43,39<->46,40<->43,40<->47,41<->44,41<->45,41<->48,42<->45,42<->46,42<->49,43<->46,43<->47,43<->50,44<->48,44<->51,45<->48,45<->49,45<->52,46<->49,46<->50,46<->53,47<->50,47<->54,48<->51,48<->52,48<->55,49<->52,49<->53,49<->56,50<->53,50<->54,50<->57,51<->55,51<->58,52<->55,52<->56,52<->59,53<->56,53<->57,53<->60,54<->57,54<->62,55<->58,55<->59,55<->61,56<->59,56<->60,56<->63,57<->60,57<->62,57<->64,58<->61,58<->65,58<->66,59<->61,59<->63,59<->67,60<->63,60<->64,60<->68,61<->66,61<->67,62<->64,62<->69,63<->67,63<->68,63<->70,64<->68,64<->69,64<->72,65<->66,65<->71,65<->73,66<->67,66<->73,66<->74,67<->70,67<->74,67<->75,68<->70,68<->72,68<->76,69<->72,69<->77,70<->75,70<->76,70<->82,71<->73,71<->78,71<->79,72<->76,72<->77,72<->83,73<->74,73<->79,73<->81,74<->75,74<->80,74<->81,75<->80,75<->82,76<->82,76<->83,76<->84,77<->83,77<->85,78<->79,78<->87,78<->88,79<->81,79<->88,79<->89,80<->81,80<->82,80<->86,80<->90,81<->89,81<->90,82<->84,82<->86,82<->91,83<->84,83<->85,83<->92,84<->91,84<->92,84<->95,85<->92,85<->97,86<->90,86<->91,86<->93,87<->88,87<->94,87<->96,88<->89,88<->96,88<->98,89<->90,89<->98,89<->99,90<->93,90<->99,90<->100,91<->93,91<->95,91<->101,92<->95,92<->97,92<->102,93<->100,93<->101,93<->105,94<->96,94<->103,94<->104,95<->101,95<->102,95<->108,96<->98,96<->104,96<->106,97<->102,97<->109,98<->99,98<->106,98<->107,99<->100,99<->107,99<->110,100<->105,100<->110,101<->105,101<->108,101<->111,102<->108,102<->109,102<->112,103<->104,103<->113,103<->114,104<->106,104<->114,104<->115,105<->110,105<->111,105<->118,106<->107,106<->115,106<->116,107<->110,107<->116,107<->117,108<->111,108<->112,108<->119,109<->112,109<->120,110<->117,110<->118,110<->124,111<->118,111<->119,111<->121,112<->119,112<->120,112<->123,113<->114,113<->122,113<->127,114<->115,114<->125,114<->127,115<->116,115<->125,115<->126,116<->117,116<->126,116<->128,117<->124,117<->128,118<->121,118<->124,118<->129,119<->121,119<->123,119<->130,120<->123,120<->131,121<->129,121<->130,121<->137,122<->127,122<->132,122<->140,123<->130,123<->131,123<->139,124<->128,124<->129,124<->135,124<->136,125<->126,125<->127,125<->133,125<->134,126<->128,126<->134,126<->138,127<->133,127<->140,128<->135,128<->138,129<->136,129<->137,129<->141,130<->137,130<->139,130<->143,131<->139,131<->142,132<->140,132<->145,133<->134,133<->140,133<->144,133<->147,134<->138,134<->144,134<->148,135<->136,135<->138,135<->146,135<->149,136<->141,136<->149,137<->141,137<->143,137<->151,138<->146,138<->148,139<->142,139<->143,139<->150,140<->145,140<->147,140<->152,141<->149,141<->151,141<->154,142<->150,142<->155,143<->150,143<->151,143<->156,144<->147,144<->148,144<->153,145<->152,145<->159,146<->148,146<->149,146<->157,146<->158,147<->152,147<->153,147<->160,148<->153,148<->158,148<->161,149<->154,149<->157,149<->162,150<->155,150<->156,150<->163,151<->154,151<->156,151<->164,152<->159,152<->160,152<->165,153<->160,153<->161,153<->166,154<->162,154<->164,154<->171,155<->163,155<->169,156<->163,156<->164,156<->170,157<->158,157<->162,157<->167,158<->161,158<->167,158<->168,159<->165,159<->172,160<->165,160<->166,160<->173,161<->166,161<->168,161<->174,162<->167,162<->171,162<->177,163<->169,163<->170,163<->175,164<->170,164<->171,164<->176,165<->172,165<->173,165<->179,166<->173,166<->174,166<->178,167<->168,167<->177,167<->180,168<->174,168<->180,169<->175,169<->181,170<->175,170<->176,170<->183,171<->176,171<->177,171<->182,172<->179,172<->184,173<->178,173<->179,173<->185,174<->178,174<->180,174<->186,175<->181,175<->183,175<->187,176<->182,176<->183,176<->189,177<->182,177<->188,177<->190,178<->185,178<->186,178<->191,179<->184,179<->185,179<->192,180<->186,180<->188,180<->193,181<->187,181<->194,182<->189,182<->190,182<->197,183<->187,183<->189,183<->196,184<->192,184<->195,185<->191,185<->192,185<->199,186<->191,186<->193,186<->200,186<->202,187<->194,187<->196,187<->198,188<->190,188<->193,188<->201,188<->203,189<->196,189<->197,189<->204,190<->197,190<->201,191<->199,191<->200,192<->195,192<->199,192<->205,193<->202,193<->203,194<->198,194<->206,195<->205,195<->207,196<->198,196<->204,196<->209,196<->211,197<->201,197<->204,197<->208,197<->210,198<->206,198<->209,199<->200,199<->205,199<->212,199<->216,200<->202,200<->212,200<->214,201<->203,201<->208,201<->213,202<->203,202<->214,202<->215,203<->213,203<->215,204<->210,204<->211,205<->207,205<->216,206<->209,206<->217,207<->216,207<->219,207<->220,208<->210,208<->213,208<->221,208<->222,209<->211,209<->218,209<->223,210<->211,210<->221,210<->224,211<->223,211<->224,212<->214,212<->216,212<->225,212<->226,213<->215,213<->222,213<->228,214<->215,214<->226,214<->227,215<->227,215<->228,216<->220,216<->225,217<->218,217<->229,218<->223,218<->229,218<->230,219<->220,219<->239,220<->225,220<->238,220<->239,221<->222,221<->224,221<->232,221<->233,222<->228,222<->233,222<->234,223<->224,223<->230,223<->231,224<->231,224<->232,225<->226,225<->237,225<->238,226<->227,226<->236,226<->237,227<->228,227<->235,227<->236,228<->234,228<->235,229<->230,230<->231,231<->232,232<->233,233<->234,234<->235,235<->236,236<->237,237<->238,238<->239}
vcoor={{0,0},{0,2},{0,4},{0,6},{0,8},{0,10},{1.763301,6.7977288},{1.7703622,5.0123738},{1.8255347,8.5823426},{1.8555534,3.2344964},{1.875,10},{1.8810692,1.4635578},{1.9565217,0},{3.4981463,5.9687987},{3.5116922,7.7418123},{3.5863269,4.0995642},{3.6986862,2.1964118},{3.75,10},{3.9130435,0},{5.0359808,5.0585682},{5.0578537,8.60972},{5.2271512,1.3851297},{5.4878778,6.817192},{5.625,10},{5.6278521,3.2748764},{5.8695652,0},{6.686425,8.4853816},{6.7061083,5.0988276},{6.9114571,1.5762933},{7.5,10},{7.5857483,6.7784267},{7.7417477,3.3626233},{7.826087,0},{8.5038116,8.3970456},{8.6224972,5.0940309},{8.7986635,1.6758317},{9.375,10},{9.4619665,6.7353382},{9.6668896,3.3939013},{9.7826087,0},{10.34461,8.3653819},{10.523498,5.082354},{10.712664,1.6940278},{11.25,10},{11.367165,6.7258895},{11.618736,3.3933568},{11.73913,0},{12.173497,8.3193691},{12.464883,5.0785619},{12.664314,1.696421},{13.125,10},{13.194525,6.7368919},{13.607426,3.3873686},{13.695652,0},{13.888325,8.2943796},{14.397414,5.0783175},{14.600672,1.6939596},{15,10},{15.045454,6.7418192},{15.497244,3.3963297},{15.555312,8.2081581},{15.652174,0},{16.326377,5.1213706},{16.537782,1.7038445},{16.666667,11.111111},{16.960079,9.1682562},{17.055561,7.043047},{17.381793,3.4121007},{17.608696,0},{18.175259,5.1554481},{18.333333,12.222222},{18.49445,1.7323965},{18.517696,10.283742},{18.64478,8.3369934},{18.902635,6.6827875},{19.427187,3.4610416},{19.565217,0},{20,13.333333},{20.155726,11.378598},{20.208219,7.4089035},{20.25594,9.369548},{20.364279,5.3472926},{20.455279,1.7512253},{21.386615,3.4678463},{21.521739,0},{21.638107,6.5883647},{21.666667,14.444444},{21.808927,12.484372},{21.923927,10.447442},{22.110516,8.3804792},{22.38837,5.0316629},{22.447173,1.7170956},{23.200294,6.6651454},{23.333333,15.555556},{23.404526,3.3832229},{23.448707,13.62717},{23.478261,0},{23.605016,11.636362},{23.873921,9.7375664},{24.035179,8.0186662},{24.373963,5.0467198},{24.434439,1.6947681},{25,16.666667},{25.096914,14.752666},{25.162619,6.66863},{25.197168,12.780351},{25.378359,10.74586},{25.386402,3.3773884},{25.434783,0},{25.949842,8.6869154},{26.378102,5.0785652},{26.397485,1.6923646},{26.666667,17.777778},{26.806055,15.795763},{26.861288,13.901985},{26.917798,12.018909},{27.000027,10.240649},{27.307584,6.8241486},{27.365388,3.3871266},{27.391304,0},{28.329207,5.0915675},{28.333333,18.888889},{28.369565,1.6943975},{28.399999,8.7131073},{28.589635,14.893326},{28.598236,12.93539},{28.628877,16.920789},{28.686369,10.921685},{29.313049,6.7615598},{29.339916,3.3957687},{29.347826,0},{30,20},{30.204368,15.866345},{30.223115,13.91478},{30.290013,9.9439293},{30.307555,8.1318838},{30.319803,5.0886049},{30.32335,11.97603},{30.326087,1.6943975},{30.568371,18.131496},{31.297155,6.7644978},{31.304348,0},{31.313027,3.4325573},{31.533926,14.873438},{31.875,20},{31.88197,10.832597},{32.039362,16.532079},{32.0916,13.06823},{32.144276,8.6911748},{32.287648,1.7178484},{32.288745,5.1644326},{32.754102,18.239128},{33.111984,14.907851},{33.243948,6.9018251},{33.26087,0},{33.27235,3.4313482},{33.361873,9.9829413},{33.513095,11.651133},{33.75,20},{33.825273,16.679563},{34.008424,13.413118},{34.220969,8.6133345},{34.23913,1.6943975},{34.252072,5.1645699},{34.709477,18.332894},{34.843425,15.053004},{34.892274,10.423136},{34.941236,12.074596},{35.217391,0},{35.247735,3.4182626},{35.291883,6.9880694},{35.625,20},{35.662502,16.748714},{35.861451,13.439334},{36.201572,1.6874426},{36.254663,5.1733886},{36.342897,8.9710503},{36.586373,15.122626},{36.612328,18.404945},{36.70698,11.450073},{37.173913,0},{37.232038,6.8596531},{37.266774,3.378958},{37.5,20},{37.636408,16.827171},{37.869217,13.363457},{38.119353,1.6285026},{38.169624,10.024717},{38.219271,5.16202},{38.229465,8.3400034},{38.33285,15.292501},{38.4375,18.376202},{38.495849,11.604645},{39.130435,0},{39.375,20},{39.399663,3.3028378},{39.453459,6.9368992},{39.790174,1.4259637},{39.793802,16.762874},{39.838761,14.464707},{39.849168,9.0010376},{39.858363,12.6747},{39.920571,10.783991},{39.98187,5.1587108},{40.059715,18.615142},{41.086957,0},{41.25,20},{41.33132,7.9844103},{41.373671,2.2486257},{41.447976,6.0869275},{41.508982,4.0397985},{41.533811,15.782357},{41.540089,9.983819},{41.570536,13.776337},{41.576517,11.869431},{41.595491,17.853299},{43.043478,0},{43.118931,1.4635578},{43.125,20},{43.174465,18.582343},{43.182735,7.0301428},{43.196048,8.970938},{43.246589,3.1184231},{43.255112,5.0221137},{43.265787,16.778314},{43.277073,14.874137},{43.287637,12.928907},{43.293243,10.923763},{45,0},{45,2},{45,4},{45,6},{45,8},{45,10},{45,12},{45,14},{45,16},{45,18},{45,20}}
eweight={95.5,7.6,97.3,89.8,30.2,140.1,82.3,49.4,132.1,73.7,60.9,112.7,65.7,85.2,65.8,57.3,61.9,77.8,68.8,95.5,62.8,89.8,56,125.4,63.6,69.3,68.3,94.1,50,163.4,62.9,102.7,45.5,99.5,74.4,87.3,112,61.6,67.1,66,84.2,99.9,55.9,139,119.3,166.5,37.8,59.6,63.1,29.2,105.6,69.5,121.7,85.8,75,66.3,67,72.4,166,89.1,64.1,112.3,79.2,59.9,62.1,49.9,186.2,96.1,33.3,112.6,67.1,80,68.4,63.8,142.3,92.6,52.1,191.8,104,61.1,62.7,67.4,111.1,83.1,60.1,178.7,105,37.2,120.1,68.2,82.5,71.1,68.1,146.4,99.3,53.9,203.9,119.2,62.8,64.8,70.9,116,89.4,64.9,185.6,115.8,41.9,129.2,71.1,86.6,76.9,72.4,155.6,108.6,54.8,216.9,130.9,66.7,72.3,76.3,124.4,98.3,68.6,196.6,126.7,43.8,139.3,77.7,94.4,86.8,79.8,169,119.1,53.6,230.4,141.2,79.5,88.3,82.8,139,110.5,72.7,208.7,133.5,45.6,149.4,80.9,108.1,100.1,85.2,184.5,126.3,55.4,246.9,149.1,103.8,78.2,107.2,88.5,157.3,109.6,68.4,227.8,140.6,71.9,126.7,46.4,158.7,83.5,202.9,131.5,56.6,265.1,154.8,113.3,72.4,110.3,127.1,65.9,132.1,184.5,47.8,147.6,65.9,248.8,146.4,44.5,166.2,67,229.4,127.9,109.9,68.5,109.3,43.3,282.9,161.5,121.9,63.4,133.8,136.4,162.3,54.9,60.2,199.2,47.8,262.6,151.8,40.7,171.7,107.3,67.1,107.6,118.6,59.7,133.3,121.7,152,182.2,49,47.9,172.3,243.8,23.3,177.8,36.3,299.1,173.6,28,283,167.4,32,175.1,81.5,204.6,116,104.8,66.3,105.2,115.2,55.8,129.1,134,38.3,157.2,208.4,16.5,156.4,43,256.3,141.2,26.1,308.9,173.3,36.8,245.6,130.8,101.1,65.5,102.2,22.9,292.9,155.4,110.5,54.8,123.6,23.6,176.2,127.8,36.4,155.6,129.4,30.2,203,216.9,51.9,36.6,269.7,137.1,20.4,316.4,168.9,96.9,64.3,98.7,102.3,56.7,117.8,39.2,261.2,110.9,117.1,35.9,140.8,165.4,15.9,145.6,13.1,301.9,151,18.3,175.4,16.4,252.1,118.6,16.1,277.8,135.1,12.9,324,166.3,92.8,63.6,93.6,92.1,111.4,54.6,97.3,39.5,141.1,105.9,30,178.8,221.1,37.5,259.6,0.7,132.6,8.9,309.4,148,12.4,173.1,4.6,287.5,134.6,84.8,65.6,81.2,7.7,328.1,163.1,76.7,228.6,-9.7,182.5,86.7,81.7,39.4,130,101.6,26.3,160.2,101.5,54.6,190.8,12.6,9.1,263.8,119,2.2,312.7,139.4,8.7,169.7,72.3,68.3,78.5,64.8,116.8,47.2,92,32.2,140.3,104.9,90.7,13.9,238.3,236.7,37.7,0,289.5,117.5,190.4,10.1,331.7,1.5,154.9,60.1,94.3,65.4,8.2,265,94.5,4.6,165.7,314.6,-2,142,48,115.1,68.3,64.8,61.7,66.7,129.7,184.3,17.1,50,116.6,59.4,18.6,189.6,50.1,252,4.9,112.5,333.6,-1.2,159.5,-2.6,292.3,125.9,58.7,86,58.9,38.4,133.1,59.4,-3.7,270.2,98.9,2.9,161.1,315.5,-5.5,140.6,69.8,201.6,42.1,38,204.9,43.1,62.6,58.6,46.7,111.8,58.9,26.7,157.1,70.7,20.5,249.4,52.4,334.6,-6.3,152.1,295.2,-14.3,121.3,57.2,81.8,56.9,35.4,139.1,61.3,77.2,246.4,-0.9,22.7,144,0.2,156.4,313.9,-10.6,142.1,265.4,-16.7,127.9,62.4,56.8,106.1,45.3,56.9,29.4,155.2,77.3,333.4,-12.2,157.4,-7,298.4,121,228.8,-9.4,183.8,30.7,152.9,55.1,55.4,83,56.9,-1.3,227.3,63.8,4.1,151.8,268,0.3,94.7,297.3,-8.1,146,62.1,55.6,94.9,46.5,61.2,39.4,133.8,10.4,132.7,338,-28.3,181.2,99.1,49.2,218.4,13.5,321.8,-29,115.5,266.2,20.1,32.7,117.3,53.5,90.3,54.2,17.2,170.9,38.1,145.7,60.2,55.1,211,30.4,325,8.4,45.2,197.2,-17.2,241.1,371.4,12.5,64.7,52.5,104.8,39,71.8,20.7,119,78.2,232.7,-1.5,84.2,10.7,154.9,180.7,2.4,3.6,303,53.7,70.3,84.6,140.9,60.5,55.3,65.7,119.7,64.8,240,-9.8,100.6,288.2,-4.1,123.8,-7.4,283.5,288.1,-12.1,69.3,58.6,33.8,117.5,78.1,217.5,2.7,74.6,18.6,143.3,7.7,180.8,49.6,91.1,121.4,137,104,401.1,38,56.8,56.2,61.8,67.9,50.7,93.4,117.2,263.2,-10.5,74.6,226.8,-7.6,114.8,329.9,-4.3,289.7,-11.9,65.5,96.7,38.3,71.8,129.6,25.4,78.6,163.4,13.7,192.5,2.3,129.4,119.1,108.3,98.3,89.2,81.1,73.8,67.3,61.7,57.9}
g=Graph[v,e,VertexCoordinates ->vcoor, EdgeWeight -> eweight, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels-> "EdgeWeight"]
```

Comment: `FindShortestPath` finds the shortest path *between two user-specified vertexes*, which is not what you've programmed.

Comment: I know it, just add this line: FindShortestPath[g,1,14]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete all the extraneous edgeweight and plotting functions because a shortest path is not well defined if you have negative weights:

```
g = Graph[v, e]

FindShortestPath[g, 44, 76]
```

(*
{44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 68, 76}
*)

Using `Method->"BellmanFord"` should work, but will not if there are negative cycles.  Perhaps your graph has such cycles:

```
AcyclicGraphQ[g]
```

(* False *)